# Sending recent posts emails to subscribers. Should we iterate over posts or subscribers as an outer loop?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance

In my app there are post subscribers and posts:

```
public class PostSubscriber {
    public List<int> Topics { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Post {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

There's a scheduled job which runs once a day that fetches recent posts (**usually a number less that 30**) and sends them to the post subscribers.

If subscriber has empty / null `Topics` list then he receives all recent posts notifications.
If subscriber has non-empty `Topics` list then he receives only the matched posts notifications.

In my current setup the outer loop is done over the posts collection and the subscribers are filtered at each iteration:

```
foreach(var post in posts) {
    var postSubscribers = preFetchedSubscribers.Where(i =>
        i.Topics == null ||
        !i.Topics.Any() ||
        i.Topics.Contains(post.Id)
    );
    ...
}
```

But I was thinking about concatenating the emails into one, sending a subscriber one letter mentioning all / matching recent posts instead of sending N letters per each post.

Would iterating over subscribers in the outer loop

```
foreach(var subscriber in subscribers) {
    foreach(var post in posts) {
        // check if post is applicable and concatenate email
    }    
    ...
    // send concatenated email
}
```

be more / less efficient and why?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenating the emails into one, there is no good way to do it other than make the subscribers the outer loop. Otherwise you would need to store the partial created emails for all subscribers until you are through with all posts.

Comment: I've been thinking the same way. Is there a significant difference in the complexity of the both variations regardless of concatenating emails?

Comment: @lexeme: In general there should be no significant difference, BUT because there are far less posts than subscribers, because of caching it could be faster to have the subscribers on the outer loop. But to be sure you should profile it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on number of posts, subscribers and number subscribed posts. If it is big enough you should consider introducing dictionary from subscribed post to subscriber (if I have calculated it correctly current implementation is `O(p * s * t)` where p - number of posts, s - number of subs, t - average number of topic per sub). Something along these lines:

```cs
var preFetchedSubscribers = new[]{new {Topics = new []{1}}};
var dictionary = preFetchedSubscribers
    .SelectMany(s => s.Topics.Select(tId => (tId, s)))
    .GroupBy(t => t.tId)
    .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Select(t => t.s).ToList());
foreach (var post in posts)
{
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(post.Id, out var subs))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or use `HashSet` instead of `List`:

```
public class PostSubscriber 
{
    public HashSet<int> Topics { get; set; } = new HashSet<int>(); // so i.Topics == null not needed
    ...
}
```

But as always - [run your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) and benchmark your concrete case.